# Revert iOS app release to an older version

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes, reverse

Once my new version is proved and release if I want to roll back, is itunes have a functionality where it will restore to the previous version or I should resubmit the old version?

Thanks

Comment: Since this isn't a programming related question. Try posting your question on http://apple.stackexchange.com/. Your question will probably get better attention there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Once an app version is approved and released to the App Store, there is no way to remove that version.  If you were still in the approval process and wanted to pull the submission and abort the process, then you could.