# Release Older Version

Tags: ios, app-store

I am in trouble.I have released my app on app store, lets say version 1.0.Now with new feature I released 1.1 on app store. After some time I came to know that my app is crashing because of specific reason.Now I want to move back to 1.0.Is it possible?If yes then show me a way...Please help me.Thanking you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Revert iOS app release to an older version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874053/revert-ios-app-release-to-an-older-version)

Answer (score 0):

You could make a 1.2 version with the same codebase as the 1.0 release and submit that as an update.
You have to go forward to go back :)